# multiple Spring Kafka Consumer one class multiple groups

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am experimenting with Apache Kafka and Spring Boot.

Is there a way to set up multiple Listeners in one JVM, Each of them associated to a different group (so that they each respond to an event) on a topic?

Is there a good pattern for this?

```
@KafkaListener(topics ="${slappy.consumer.topic}", groupId = "t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10")
public void listenToGroup(@Payload WackyMessage message) {

    log.info("Wacky Consumer with processItemId of received message: '{}'", message);

    process(message, ProcessItemIdentifiers.omni_silo0_deleter);
}
```

Sounds like this is the sort of thing Akka is for.  I was hoping I could just do naked spring.  I am not sure If I want to add Akka into the mix at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your possible `groupId = "t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10"` solution is logically wrong. You still have the same listener method, so what is the point to call it so many times for the same record in Kafka topic?

If you would have different `@KafkaListener` methodd signatures, I would agree with you about different groups on them, so each of them would really receive the same message and it could be done in parallel as well, since each `@KafkaListener` blows up its own *listener container* process.

On the other hand you can leverage an `@EventListener` abstraction from Spring to distribute a single record from a single `@KafkaListener` to any possible number of subscribers to that event. In this case you don't need to think about different groups: the single one is enough to consumer from Kafka and process everything rest in the target application already.

Comment: So multiple methods is fine.  The thing is that the method would that would be executing would be exactly the same.  As I was hoping that there was a slightly more elegant solution.  But multiple methods is fine.

Comment: I just don't understand the point of calling the same method for the same data several time and do everything form Kafka consumer thread. Why can't you just have a loop in your single `@KafkaListener` method then?

Comment: We could have a loop in the one listener as well... So the method right now edits a database (delete,udate,insert).  I want this to execute on 11 different copies of a database.  I could spin up threads to do this in parallel also, I am just wondering if there is an elegant solution.  Like I noticed that you can annotate a listener for multiple topics:
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic1, topic2", groupId = "foo")

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look into Spring Boot and its auto-configuration for Spring Kafka: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-kafka. So, you can spin as many instances of your Microservice as you need and each of them will come with its own `groupId' and its own database connectivity. This way you indeed will have the same code, but it is going to be performed against different environments and the same record from Kafka.

Comment: Looking through the docs it isn' readily apparent what configurations I can set...  It would seem they want me to build my own KafkaListenerContainerFactory...
I would love an example of building that + example configurations that put that together.

Comment: Here you can find some samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/master/samples. All of them are Spring Boot based.

Comment: You can provide your configuration properties and use Properties Placeholders in the `groupId` option of the `@KafkaListener`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation